# Is Firebase now mandatory for use of Google Analytics Mobile Properties?

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-analytics

Is Firebase now *required* for setting up Google Analytics for Mobile?  In the past, when I've setup Google Analytics for Mobile, I've selected "Mobile" from the Create New Property view and gotten the standard Analytics key (e.g., "UA-BLAHBLAH-BL").  However, when I went to setup a new property today, that is not what is happening.  Instead, I am seeing this:

[image: The new create property view]

It appears that there is now no way to use the traditional Google Analytics SDK for new properties using the analytics key of olde.

Am I correct in this deduction?  Or is there some other way to setup a new Mobile property with an analytics key of the past that I have missed?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Re-iterating the steps here from the same document for information to be available in same post:

1. Sign in to your [Google Analytics account](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/#home/).
2. Click Admin.
3. In the PROPERTY column, select Create new property from the dropdown menu.
4. Select Website.
5. Provide a Website Name. You may use the name of your app.
6. Provide a Website URL. You may use your company URL or the URL for your app’s marketing site.
7. Click Get Tracking ID.
8. In the VIEW column, select Create new view from the dropdown menu.
9. Select Mobile app.
10. Provide a Reporting View Name.
11. Click Create View

Comment: That way the view won't show the mobile app properties

Answer (score 8):

Google have published instructions on how to set up a new mobile property using the Google Analytics Services SDK.

You can find them in Google Support, Analytics Help as [Analytics for mobile apps](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2587086?hl=en).

Comment: I set up a mobile property as described in the link you provided.  I then did a bunch of activity and checked GA the next day to see what was logged and how it compared to other mobile properties I'd set up under the previous method.  It seems to be a good match.  Thanks for finding that doc link in help center.  I'd like to accept your answer, but do you think you could improve it by including the steps described in the linked document?