# Add Google Analytics to Android app without Firebase

Tags: android, google-analytics

Has anyone actually tried adding Google Analytics to Android app without using Firebase recently? I can't seem to find the way to get the GA Tracking ID.
I actually managed to do it last year by creating the project in Google Developer Console first before adding GA.

Now GA doesn't even give the option of importing mobile app project without using Firebase.
Anyone with similar experience?

The reason I am asking for this is because adding GA with or without Firebase shows different console interface. And the app with GA via Firebase doesn't show up on the GA Android App.

Comment: try google script to load it in a web view?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Found a workaround to use Google Analytics for Mobile Apps without using Firebase.

Steps:

1. Create a new Google Analytics Property.
2. You will be asked "What would you like to track?"

---

If you choose Website:
[image: Website Option]

---

If you choose Mobile App:
[image: Mobile App Option]

---

You will notice that there is no option to create a tracking ID for Mobile Apps.

3. Select Website and simply fill in the Website Name and URL.

A tracking ID will be generated for you.

An "All Web Site Data" view will be created for you.

4. Open Administration of your account by selecting the Settings icon.
5. Choose the newly created Property
6. Click on the View dropdown and select "Create new view"
   [image: Select "Create new view"]
7. Select "Mobile app" and fill in the view name
   [image: Fill in the view name]
8. Done! Now, you can delete the web site data view.

Comment: Total lifesaver. Thank you!

Comment: A similar but a text-only answer is at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44467365/984471

Comment: I think in 2023 (or earlier?) this no longer works.  AFAICT, GAv4 Analytics Properties no longer have "Views".  I think the "Data Stream" is the new View (?);  But creating an Android data stream within a Web Property still routes you to the Firebase SDK.  (If you're still using a "Universal Analytics" UI, then maybe the above still applies?)